# HttpWebRequest with proxy exception

Tags: c#, proxy, get, httpwebrequest, webexception

I have a next problem: when I try to create a `HttpWebRequest` with proxy, I get a `WebException` with the message

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://msdn.microsoft.com/");

    webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("109.254.143.7", 1080);
    webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    //webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

    var myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    var stream = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    var text = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

P.S.: It happens only when I try to use the proxy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it looks like the proxy is closing the connection, just as the exception indicates. Are you sure it _is_ an HTTP proxy and that you're allowed to use it?

Comment: oh, I really didn't notice, that I'm using a SOCKS proxy, thanks! :)
But some HTTP proxies throws me an other errors, like:

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

and 

"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"